# We were able to use him

Tags: word-choice

> Due to his outstanding knowledge in the field we were able to **use** Mr. Bean as a senior developer in international projects.

Is “use” the correct word here? I'm afraid it might sound a bit as if Mr. Bean were an object rather than a person. Would you rather use something like “employ”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People routinely use the word "use" in this context. I don't see anything offensive about it. Of course, there are always people who work hard at being offended.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest *appoint* or *engage*.

Answer (score -1):

I think “trust” or “announce” may be better. By using the word “use” you objectify the person.

Comment: This is where context is so important. If I said, _She meant nothing to me; I was just using her_; then _use_ takes on [Definition #4](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/use). In the O.P.'s sentence, though, the term is clearly meant in a complimentary fashion, and thus aligns with [Definition #1](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/use). I see no problem with the O.P.'s sentence – even if I were Mr. Bean, I'd feel the same way.